# Pytorch tensor indexing

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I am currently working on converting some code from tensorflow to pytorch, I encountered problem with [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) func, there is no direct function to convert it in pytorch.

What I am trying to do is basically indexing, I have two tensors, feature tensor shapes of `[minibatch, 60, 2]` and indexing tensor `[minibatch, 8]`, say like first tensor is tensor `A`, and the second one is `B`.

In Tensorflow, it is directly converted with `tf.gather(A, B, batch_dims=1)`

How do I achieve this in pytorch?

I have tried `A[B]` indexing. This seems not work

and `A[0]B[0]` works, but output of shape is `[8, 2]`

I need the shape of `[minibatch, 8, 2]`

It will probably work if I stack tensor like `[stack, 8, 2]` but I have no idea how to do it

```
tensorflow
out = tf.gather(logits, indices, batch_dims=1)
```

```
pytorch
out = A[B] -> something like this will be great
```

Output shape of `[minibatch, 8, 2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather)

```py
out = torch.gather(A, 1, B[..., None].expand(*B.shape, A.shape[-1]))
```

Comment: @AydenLee glad I could help. If this answer works for you, please consider"accepting" it by clicking the "v" icon beside it